# Breadcrumb's triangles using images and :before, :after pseudoelements

Tags: css

Problematic part:

```
.breadcrumbs a:before, .breadcrumbs span:before {
    background: url('');
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background-position: 0 -147px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
}
```

I am trying to make some padding for the text but I can't find any workaround that wouldn't affect image from the `:before` pseudoelement.

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/ZARUz/
I am trying to obtain that effect: http://cl.ly/SVBR

Comment: We can't see your local image files. Use hosted files so we can understand your question better.

Comment: Pretty sure that's not a local file. The fiddle works just fine.  http://s1.pixelize.pl/breadcrumb.png

Comment: sorry, my bad, it's my work internet blocking the image. Just assumed it was a local url as the image didn't show

Comment: A tutorial link to make it complete in css without images.. http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-breadcrumbs

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/TreeTree/ZARUz/12/

```
.breadcrumbs a, .breadcrumbs span {
    height: 20px;
    background: url('http://s1.pixelize.pl/breadcrumb.png');
    background-position: 0 -21px;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.breadcrumbs a:after, .breadcrumbs span:after {
    background: url('http://s1.pixelize.pl/breadcrumb.png') white;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background-position: 0 -63px;
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
}
.breadcrumbs a:before, .breadcrumbs span:before {
    background: url('http://s1.pixelize.pl/breadcrumb.png');
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background-position: 0 -147px;
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left:-10px;
}
```

Your pseudos weren't given `left` and `right` properties which made them slightly unpredictable.

I assumed by

> that wouldn't affect image from the :before pseudoelement.

you meant modifying the actual image file, so this method doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Need to position your before and after "blocks" so the backgrounds can appear correctly.

[A JSFiddle Lives Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PRsQX/)

```
.breadcrumbs a, .breadcrumbs span {
    height: 20px;
    background: url('http://s1.pixelize.pl/breadcrumb.png');
    background-position: 0 -21px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.breadcrumbs a:after, .breadcrumbs span:after {
    background: url('http://s1.pixelize.pl/breadcrumb.png');
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background-position: 0 -63px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
}

.breadcrumbs a:before, .breadcrumbs span:before {
    background: url('http://s1.pixelize.pl/breadcrumb.png');
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background-position: 0 -147px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
}
```